# So what do we call ourselves now?

Tags: discussion

Apparenly "Stackers" was the [early accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/what-should-the-users-of-stackoverflow-be-called) for SO, and I'm sure there are "fault tolerants", "meta junkies", and "super friends" out there as well. But with the upcoming dev days and such, what are we going to call those "all purpose" folks that are trying to thrive in the whole community?

Flow jockeys?
S-Heads?
SCubies? (bad variant of S Cubed combined with too much Scooby-Doo my kids are watching lately)

Somtehing else?

Comment: There's a really good joke answer here, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: I'm a moderator of the Thuper Youthers

Comment: What about the horrible sofu's  or by it regexp ^s[ofu]$

Answer (score 15):

You can call me "Sir".

Comment: I thought it was "Al"?

Answer (score 11):

Oh, good lord. Please, no.

The day someone starts labeling any Stackoverflow user as "Stacker" or a "Stackee" or a *Something-Or-Other* Badgie... is the day I start *anonomous-izing* my account. Can you say "pop-culture-burnout, jumping-the-shark"?

Comment: Not easily - that's a mouthful!

Answer (score 7):

I'd start by using their first name...

Comment: The question is not about the individuals, but the group as a whole.

Comment: I upvoted this just to annoy Stu

Comment: I upvoted this for the same reason The did.

Comment: Ah! Shucks, guys!  Now I know you really care!

Answer (score 5):

Call me Ishmael.

Answer (score 5):

I am Spartacus.

Oh and I always said the proper term is "nerds" and then people will follow the pattern and correct me declaring the correct term is "geeks"

Comment: Let's combine them.  Do you want neeks or gerds?

Comment: @Pesto: That's what you get when nerds and geeks interbreed.

Comment: @gnovice: Don't be silly.  What are the chances of a nerd or a geek breeding?

Comment: @Pesto: Well who the hell else are nerds and geeks going to breed with other than each other?!

Answer (score 2):

I like to refer to 'us' as **SOpedians**.

Stack Overflow is supposed to have this wiki-like attribute, so...hehe?

Comment: That looks too similar to Soapians ...

Comment: And?  Sorry...not getting your point.