# Demonym (nickname) for a Stack Exchange user?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, community, terminology, culture

I wonder if there is a noun meaning a person who uses Stack Exchange.

Please see this question.

[What is the equivalent of a demonym, but for organizations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585375/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-demonym-but-for-organizations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is “Stacker” a common term for Stack Overflow members?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336797/is-stacker-a-common-term-for-stack-overflow-members)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. not dupe. Stacker is SO only, this question is about whole of Stack Exchange, much bigger scope.

Comment: Migrate to [elu.se] ;-)

Comment: Related, on Meta SO: [Is there a name for Stack Overflow users as a whole?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318195/is-there-a-name-for-stack-overflow-users-as-a-whole)

Comment: Please add sample statements and their respective contexts.

Comment: @Rubén I imagine things like "Wikipedians follow rules more strictly than StackExchangians" or "As a Stackizen I understand the value of duplicate closure" etc.

Answer (score 7):

Singular: User. Plural: Users or Community.

---

There might be other nouns depending on users preferred activity, specific role (asker, answerer, reviewer, moderator...) or experience, (new user, ...)

Since Stack Exchange is not really a Social Media, it doesn't allow chitchat<sup>1</sup> and each site has a very specific scope, whenever there is a call to action there is no need to use a *nickname* to address the Stack Exchange community as a whole.

From the Meta SE tour

> Meta Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network.

Please note the above text don't use any *nickname*, it use **you**, **your**, **we**, **together**.

1 : [Expected Behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

---

### Related

#### Meta SE

- [Can we ban the term "Stacker"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6244/289691) from 2009
- [So what do we call ourselves now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10121/289691) from 2009
- [Is the term USERS the right word to describe active members on Stack Exchange Sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220278/289691) from 2014
- [Is “Stacker” a common term for Stack Overflow members?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336797/289691) from 2019

#### Stack Overflow

- [Is there a name for Stack Overflow users as a whole?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318195/1595451) from 2016